# Error while listing files in directory recursively using python

Tags: python

I am trying to list all the file ending with '.py'. The way I want it to be displayed is `dirname` + `filename`. I am using `os.path.join()` for this. I am getting an error when I put `/Users` as the starting point. **But when I specify the directory where most of the '.py' files are like `os.walk(r'/Users/name/Pythonfiles')` I don't get the error.**

This is the code I came up with:

```
for cdir, dir, files in os.walk(r'/Users'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            filename = os.path.join(cdir, file)
            print filename
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/PythonTutorials/finding_largest_file.py", line 9, in <module>
     filename = os.path.join(dir, file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
     elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ends with'
```

And please suggest a better way to accomplish this task if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong value in your `os.path.join()` call. The current directory being iterated over is the first value given by `os.walk()`, which you assigned to `cdir`.

You are using the *second* value returned by `os.walk()`, which is a list of directory names.

Use:

```
for cdir, directories, files in os.walk(r'/Users'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            filename = os.path.join(cdir, file)
            print filename
```

I renamed `dir` to `directories`; a clearer name and also one that doesn't mask the built-in `dir()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But could you let me know if there is any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Good thing that you renamed `dir` - you should probably do the same for `file` ;)

Comment: @ShandeepMurugasamy: and by 'more efficient' you mean, what, exactly? There is no faster method of iterating over all the directories recursively. Python 3.5 uses a faster implementation for the OS call to gather the directory information, but there is nothing you can do in older Python versions to make this go faster.

Comment: @alfasin: `file` is deprecated and even removed in Python 3. It is far less of a problem when you still have `open()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not using Python 3... Thanks for the info - always good to learn something new!